CP-SAT freezing soon after starting to solve with 8 or more workers
I am experiencing this for all formulations now. Previously I had no issues.
Take this example:
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
from typing import List, Optional
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model

n = 8  # Board size and number of queens
model = cp_model.CpModel()

# Create variables - queens[i] represents the column position of queen in row i
queens = [model.NewIntVar(0, n - 1, f"queen_{i}") for i in range(n)]

# No two queens in same column
model.AddAllDifferent(queens)

# No two queens in same diagonal
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        model.Add(queens[i] - queens[j] != i - j)
        model.Add(queens[i] - queens[j] != j - i)

# Solve
solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 10
solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
solver.parameters.num_search_workers = 8
status = solver.Solve(model)

This code freezes indefinitely just after starting to solve. Output:
Starting CP-SAT solver v9.11.4210
Parameters: max_time_in_seconds: 10 log_search_progress: true num_search_workers: 8

Initial satisfaction model '': (model_fingerprint: 0x6856406a4ac1332d)
#Variables: 8
  - 8 in [0,7]
#kAllDiff: 1
#kLinear2: 56 (#complex_domain: 56)

Starting presolve at 0.00s
  1.10e-05s  0.00e+00d  [DetectDominanceRelations] 
  1.49e-04s  0.00e+00d  [PresolveToFixPoint] #num_loops=2 #num_dual_strengthening=1 
  2.00e-06s  0.00e+00d  [ExtractEncodingFromLinear] 
[Symmetry] Graph for symmetry has 552 nodes and 944 arcs.
[Symmetry] Symmetry computation done. time: 0.000165 dtime: 0.00029732
[Symmetry] #generators: 1, average support size: 72
[Symmetry] 36 orbits with sizes: 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,...
[Symmetry] Num fixable by intersecting at_most_one with orbits: 4 largest_orbit: 2
[SAT presolve] num removable Booleans: 0 / 64
[SAT presolve] num trivial clauses: 0
[SAT presolve] [0s] clauses:252 literals:504 vars:60 one_side_vars:60 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [1.3e-05s] clauses:252 literals:504 vars:60 one_side_vars:60 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
[SAT presolve] [2e-05s] clauses:252 literals:504 vars:60 one_side_vars:60 simple_definition:0 singleton_clauses:0
...
#2       0.00s default_lp (fixed_bools=0/60)
#3       0.00s quick_restart (fixed_bools=0/60)
#4       0.00s quick_restart_no_lp (fixed_bools=0/60)
#Model   0.11s var:59/60 constraints:114/114

If I update the num search workers to any number below 8 then there are no issues.
Has anyone seen this before?

What is the output of os.cpu_count()?

os.cpu_count() yields 11

which platform ?

MacOS Sonoma 14.3. arm64. python 3.11.8

Works fine on the next release
#Model   0.00s var:60/60 constraints:43/43

Starting search at 0.00s with 8 workers.
6 full problem subsolvers: [default_lp, max_lp, no_lp, probing, quick_restart, quick_restart_no_lp]
2 first solution subsolvers: [fj, fs_random_no_lp]
2 interleaved subsolvers: [feasibility_pump, rins/rens]
2 helper subsolvers: [neighborhood_helper, synchronization_agent]

#1       0.00s no_lp
#2       0.00s fj_restart(batch:1 lin{mvs:44 evals:60} #w_updates:24 #perturb:0)

Task timing                      n [     min,      max]      avg      dev     time         n [     min,      max]      avg      dev    dtime
           'default_lp':         1 [431.00us, 431.00us] 431.00us   0.00ns 431.00us         1 [337.07us, 337.07us] 337.07us   0.00ns 337.07us
     'feasibility_pump':         1 [200.00us, 200.00us] 200.00us   0.00ns 200.00us         0 [  0.00ns,   0.00ns]   0.00ns   0.00ns   0.00ns
                   'fj':         1 [ 80.00us,  80.00us]  80.00us   0.00ns  80.00us         1 [ 63.61us,  63.61us]  63.61us   0.00ns  63.61us
      'fs_random_no_lp':         1 [254.00us, 254.00us] 254.00us   0.00ns 254.00us         0 [  0.00ns,   0.00ns]   0.00ns   0.00ns   0.00ns
               'max_lp':         1 [402.00us, 402.00us] 402.00us   0.00ns 402.00us         0 [  0.00ns,   0.00ns]   0.00ns   0.00ns   0.00ns
                'no_lp':         1 [332.00us, 332.00us] 332.00us   0.00ns 332.00us         1 [376.61us, 376.61us] 376.61us   0.00ns 376.61us
              'probing':         1 [340.00us, 340.00us] 340.00us   0.00ns 340.00us         0 [  0.00ns,   0.00ns]   0.00ns   0.00ns   0.00ns
        'quick_restart':         1 [385.00us, 385.00us] 385.00us   0.00ns 385.00us         1 [334.29us, 334.29us] 334.29us   0.00ns 334.29us
  'quick_restart_no_lp':         1 [375.00us, 375.00us] 375.00us   0.00ns 375.00us         1 [352.17us, 352.17us] 352.17us   0.00ns 352.17us
            'rins/rens':         0 [  0.00ns,   0.00ns]   0.00ns   0.00ns   0.00ns         0 [  0.00ns,   0.00ns]   0.00ns   0.00ns   0.00ns

Search stats              Bools  Conflicts  Branches  Restarts  BoolPropag  IntegerPropag
           'default_lp':     60          5       468       255       3'344              0
      'fs_random_no_lp':     60          0       108       108       1'216              0
               'max_lp':     60          0       120       120       1'340          1'460
                'no_lp':     60         15       481       255       3'510              0
              'probing':     60          0       120       120       1'340              0
        'quick_restart':     60          5       454       255       3'351              0
  'quick_restart_no_lp':     60          8       483       255       3'427              0

SAT stats                 ClassicMinim  LitRemoved  LitLearned  LitForgotten  Subsumed  MClauses  MDecisions  MLitTrue  MSubsumed  MLitRemoved  MReused
           'default_lp':             0           0          53             0         0        32         208         0          0            0        0
      'fs_random_no_lp':             0           0           0             0         0         0           0         0          0            0        0
               'max_lp':             0           0           0             0         0         0           0         0          0            0        0
                'no_lp':             2           3         169             0         0        32         208         0          0            0        0
              'probing':             0           0           0             0         0         0           0         0          0            0        0
        'quick_restart':             0           0          49             0         0        32         208         0          0            0        0
  'quick_restart_no_lp':             3           5         100             0         0        32         208         0          0            0        0

Lp stats     Component  Iterations  AddedCuts  OPTIMAL  DUAL_F.  DUAL_U.
  'max_lp':          1           0          0        0        0        0

Lp dimension    Final dimension of first component
     'max_lp':    43 rows, 60 columns, 266 entries

Lp debug     CutPropag  CutEqPropag  Adjust  Overflow  Bad  BadScaling
  'max_lp':          0            0       0         0    0           0

Lp pool      Constraints  Updates  Simplif  Merged  Shortened  Split  Strenghtened  Cuts/Call
  'max_lp':           43        0        0       0          0      0             0        0/0

LNS stats       Improv/Calls  Closed  Difficulty  TimeLimit
  'rins/rens':           0/0      0%    5.00e-01       0.10

LS stats         Batches  Restarts/Perturbs  LinMoves  GenMoves  CompoundMoves  Bactracks  WeightUpdates  ScoreComputed
  'fj_restart':        1                  1        44         0              0          0             24             60

Solution repositories    Added  Queried  Synchro
  'feasible solutions':      2        0        2
   'fj solution hints':      0        0        0
        'lp solutions':      0        0        0
                'pump':      0        0

CpSolverResponse summary:
status: OPTIMAL
objective: NA
best_bound: NA
integers: 0
booleans: 60
conflicts: 15
branches: 481
propagations: 3510
integer_propagations: 0
restarts: 255
lp_iterations: 0
walltime: 0.00413
usertime: 0.00413
deterministic_time: 0.0022054
gap_integral: 0
solution_fingerprint: 0x5e595bf00f728210

